# Fire heat organism

Tags: xenobiology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

My organism produce cooled plasma for defense .It lives in planet with very exotic flora and fauna which have super powers . It preys big whales and trex like organism. My question is that how my organism produce cold plasma (100 °c) without energy intensive process ?

Comment: What exactly is a cooled plasma?

Comment: Isn't raising something's temperature to 100°C naturally expensive by definition? Unless the planet is at 100°c, too, but what would make this product useful as a defense then, if everyone is accustomed to this same temperature?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, by "cooled plasma" you mean something like [nonthermal plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonthermal_plasma), which is sometimes referred to as "cold plasma".

It doesn't really matter though, because regardless of what you meant, you still need to get that material ionized, and ionization is energetically expensive. Here's a [handy chart of ionization energies of all the elements](https://periodictableguide.com/ionization-energy-chart-of-all-elements) for reference.

Lets take something relatively commonplace and not too difficult to ionize, such as iron (7.9eV). Given the [molar mass of iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass) (55.845 g/mol) and [Avogadro's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant), you can see that a single gram of iron has nearly 1.1x10x<sup>22</sup> atoms. To ionize 1% of them, you need to expend 136 joules. I'm not sure how fast they'll recombine, but plasma doesn't like to stay plasma at room temperature. Maybe it all recombines in a millisecond, which means that maintaining 100g of partially ionized iron requires 1.36 *megajoules* per second. That's an awful lot of steak right there... consider that the same amount of energy is enough to boil several liters of water, or get several hours of work out of a few humans.

Fluorescent lights and other sources of non-thermal plasma generate very small amounts in a confined space, often under low pressure. This requires much less energy to initiate and maintain.

It isn't obvious how you'd use your nonthermal plasma as a weapon or some other kind of defensive system, but regardless of what you were intending you could use that same energy to do a whole bunch of other things that would be an awful lot more effective (such as running away *very fast*, or hauling around a really serious exoskeleton or tough hide).